# async callback api nested inside new promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, promise

I want to wrap an async node_module function (xml2js - parseString) in a promise. However I have a worry that I may be creating a race condition where the promise code somehow resolves before the nested async parseString function has finished. Could this potentially happen? Every so often we do get a "Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded." during tests. I'm trying to eliminate the cause.

my Promise function

```
map1(soapResponse) {
   var promise = new Promise(function(resolve) {

     parseString(soapResponse[config.responseProperty], {
       ignoreAttrs: true,
       explicitArray: false
     }, function(err, jsObject) {
       let policyDAO = new PolicyDAO()

       policyDAO.givenName = jsObject["aeroplanes"]["aeroplane"]["given-name"]

       return resolve(policyDAO);
     });
   })

   return promise
 }
```

using the function -

```
var policyMapper = new PolicyMapper()
policyMapper.map1(soapResponse)
  .then(function (policy) {
    //synchronised code
  })
```

supertest -

```
var request = require('supertest')
var app = require('app')

describe('get /details', function () {
  it('return 200 (OK) and username for policy 999999', function (done) {
    request(app).post('/').send({id: '999999'})
      .expect(200)
      .expect(/CHARLES SMITH/, done);
  });

})
```

I'm using node (v6.2.2), ES6, express, mocha, chai, supertest

Comment: Where does the `resolve` come from in `return resolve(policy);` on the last line?

Comment: You say the timeout occurs during testing... do you mean in a mocha test? if so, can you post the test code?

Comment: @nem035 - apologies, return resolve(policy); has since been removed. I will update the code above

Comment: @Kryten test added

Comment: in your test, add a `return` statement: `(done) => { return request(app).... }`

Comment: @DavidStewart I don't see where in in your test are you using the problematic `PolicyMapper`?

Comment: Also, @DavidStewart maybe the `parseString` function is slow and thus sometimes exceeds the mocha's default timeout. Did you try [increasing](http://mochajs.org/#timeouts) it?

Comment: @Kryten, I refactored the code to use chaining and the error continued to occur sporadically. My concerns that nested promises cause race conditions were unfounded. I know now chaining is the correct utilization regardless.